# How to keep angular mat-panel-title text sticky in the screen?

Tags: css, angular, material-ui, angular-material, angular-material2

I have an angular material accordion like the below.

The problem is if I scroll right the title "Angular Framework" is moving left and it is going away from the screen. I want to keep the title in the screen always though the user scrolls right.

Tried position sticky but it is not working. Can you suggest? If the question is not clear, let me know.

```html
   <mat-accordion>
     <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let title of frameworks; first as isFirst" [expanded]="isFirst">
       <mat-expansion-panel-header class="custom-panel-header" [style]="getBackgroundColor(title)">
         <mat-panel-title [style]="getBackgroundColor(title)" style="position:sticky!important;left:0">
           {{ title }} Framework
         </mat-panel-title>
       </mat-expansion-panel-header>
       <div>
         <svg id="{{ title }}-Framework" class="frame-base"></svg>
       </div>
     </mat-expansion-panel>
   </mat-accordion>
```